# Fields randomly being visible in InfoPath form

Tags: infopath

I have rules on an InfoPath 2013 form where if a check box is checked, a field should show.
If I fill the form in order from top to bottom, I don't have any issues. However, if I fill certain fields out in the middle of the form and get to it, the field won't show even if the check box is checked. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a browser form? If so, you may want to set postback to always on your checkbox and see if that resolves the formatting issue. Right click the checkbox and select Check Box Properties. Click on the Browser tab and select "Always" for the postback settings.

Comment: That didn't work. I'm still having the same issue. Is there any other recommendation?

Comment: Generally in a browser form, postback takes care of most issues. I guess my next approach would be to create a sample form and see if I could get the issue to reproduce.